# Words related to reading

Tags: synonyms, reading

Can anyone please pile up the words related to reading?e.g read,browse and peruse.
simple explanation of the words welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, user132235, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. One of the restrictions on questions at this site is they should not be open-ended, in the sense of soliciting lists of every word that fits a particular category—and unfortunately your question falls precisely into that disapproved area. If you can recast your question to ask for something more specific, please consider doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ,how should I make it close-ended?any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to ask you to try a thesaurus, but then I tried a thesaurus, and was quite disappointed.  So I will use the other approach, and reach into my head, kind of like free-associating.

Consume

Devour

Skim

Decipher

Absorb

Follow along

Decode

Speed through

Savor

Edify oneself

Learn

Study

Capture the essence

Sample

Comment: I found 16 synonyms in the first search for "browse synonym" I tried. And some of these suggestions are peripheral to say the least. 'Bookmark', 'table lamp' and 'reading glasses' might fit OP's (far too broad) request better.